# Email from "c.cs17.visual.force.com" domain won't send

Tags: email

This is part of a bigger problem, but...

Emails sent from "https://something--poc--c.cs17.visual.force.com/email/author/emailauthor.jsp"  will NOT send.

However, emails from " https://something--poc.cs17.my.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor"  WILL send.

I'm using Conga composer.  I really need help getting the first link to work.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a Sandbox environment. Have you set the email deliverability for email in your sandbox? It is in Setup>Email Administration>Deliverability set the Access to the Send Email to "All Email". The default upon refresh is "No Access"

the --sandbox--c.cs##.visual.force.com domain is for custom visualforce pages. I was able to see the same behavior in my org. I think you should just use the standard domain and not the visualforce one since you are not using a visualforce page.

Comment: ah yes, I forgot to mention that I did.  It's set to "all email".

Comment: added an edit. Do not use the visualforce domain.

Comment: So there's no way to making the VF domain work at all, eh?  I'm arriving to it from Conga Composer, via a custom VF page, and the Conga support guys... are pretty stumped and not sure how to change the domain that I land at.

Comment: It is not a visualforce page,  so I would guess that is why it will not work.

Comment: You contacted Conga support and they say it is working like this for other Conga users?

Comment: Well, they frankly didn't really know what to do or why it wasn't working.  THey're looking at it and hopefully they get back to me... but I've been on the phone with them for a combined 3 hours today so far, no joke, on various other issues.  Great people but I guess I know why they don't officially support Conga being launched from a VF page.